# How do I add Advanced Scene Switcher plugin to OBS?

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-studio, obs-studio

Just installed Ubuntu Studio, and I need Advanced Scene Switcher plugin. How do I install it?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how OBS Studio was installed. You can see if it's installed as a snap by running: `snap list`

If it's installed as a snap, this plugin should already be included (according to the [project's Github page](https://github.com/WarmUpTill/SceneSwitcher)).

If OBS Studio is installed as a `.deb` package, you can install the [obs-advanced-scene-switcher](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/jammy/obs-advanced-scene-switcher) plugin from the [Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository/).

```
sudo apt install obs-advanced-scene-switcher
```

Comment: Not listed in snap list. Tried to install as a .deb - does not work either. I tried the Ubuntu Studio because it had OBS included with the install.  But I need the NDI and Advanced Scene Switcher plugins or it is useless.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with how OBS Studio is installed by default in Ubuntu Studio - I was trying to provide a solution based on the documentation - but maybe that isn't enough. 